# How to handle global template variables in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

In my `Laravel application`, I have some global part of sites which is the same in all pages and that part is the header.

In the header, there is some basic information like a number of unread notifications, username and some data I need to read from the `database`.

Everytime I open any controller I need to do the same query and get the data just so I can display it. What's the best way to handle that situation so I don't have to duplicate logic in every controller and its action? How to handle those global cases?

Comment: see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your variable in boot method of  **App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**:

```
public function boot() {

    $city_list = City::all();

    View::share( 'cities', $city_list );
    View::share( 'show_sidebar', true );
    View::share( 'my_var', 'yes' );

}
```